# Selection of regressors

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, model-selection

I have a question about the package **leaps** which I am using for model selection.

I would like to compare 4 different selection methods: forward, backward, stepwise and best subset. I used the code below:

```
library(leaps)
forward <- regsubsets(Response ~.,data = mydata, method = "forward", nbest=1)  
backward <- regsubsets(Response ~.,data = mydata, method = "backward", nbest=1)
stepwise <- regsubsets(Response ~., data = mydata, method = "seqrep", nbest=1)
best subset <- regsubsets(Response ~.,data = mydata, method = "exhaustive", nbest=1)
# adjusted R2
opt = par (mfrow =c(2,2))
plot(forward, scale = "adjr2", main = "Forward Selection")
plot(backward, scale = "adjr2", main = "Backward Selection")
plot(stepwise, scale = "adjr2", main = "Stepwise selection")
plot(best subset, scale = "adjr2", main = "Best subset selection")
```

Using these commands I obtained figures below: 
[image]

I am wondering why figure A and D are similar to each other (and also figure B and C). I would expect different algorithms to select models in a different way. For instance models selected with forward selection method should be chosen based on the significance level/ AIC value. On the other hand models selected with best subset selection method should be chosen based on the sample statistics.

I am also wondering why forward selection does not choose one variable at the time adding it to the existing model?

Also Fig B shows that backward selection starts with eight variables in the model. Why it does not start with all the variables and excludes one at the time?

Answer (score 1):

1. I ran the forward and exhaustive algorithms on the data set that I am working right now and found out the plots to be different.

   leaps = regsubsets(orders_rcvd~., data=data[,var_cols], nbest=1, method="forward")
   plot(leaps)
   leaps = regsubsets(orders_rcvd~., data=data[,var_cols], nbest=1, method="exhaustive")
   plot(leaps)

[image]
I am guessing that for your dataset the models selected by the forward search for each of the number of the variables is the same the best subset for each of the number of variables by the best-subset algorithm.

Question 2 and 3 : The algorithm does work in the way you mentioned. But the plots are not the visual representation of the path the algorithm has taken. Its y-axis is sorted by the Adjusted-R^2, in your case